# How to add row elements as a object in arraylist?

Tags: java, object, arraylist

I have a row with like 7 attributes with three unique ids.I want to add all this attributes as an object in array list. How to do so?

Suppose,

```
Person ID   LastName    MiddleName  FirstName   Address City Time   State
```

has a table structure.

suppose there is another row above that one in the table. Now 112 id remains in 3 rows,  113 id in another 3 row, and 114 id in last row.So we have rows with id 112, 113,and 114 in the table.
Now I want the first 3 rows as 3 objects of array list 1. Then next 3 rows as 3 objects of arraylist 2. And last row as 1 object of arraylist3.
so in total I want 3 arraylist .

How to solve the above requirement?

Comment: Can you sharesome codes ? It's very vague

Comment: What is a row? give an example

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Your question is quite vague. but if you're simply looking to add an object to `ArrayList`, simply call the `add()` method. more details can be found in the Javadoc https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#add-E-

Comment: 1. Create an object containing all attributes. 2. Add to arraylist. There is nothing more to that than this.

Comment: I already gave you an answer bellow. Though, from your question, I understand that you are new in Java. Take a little time to read about Object Oriented Programming in general, not specifically in Java, so that to acquire the mindset you need.

Answer (score 1):

Given this little information I understand that you have a "table" with 7 columns and you want to store each row in an ArrayList.

First thing you have to do is to create a Class, eg. MyRow and add the 7 attributes as the class fields.

Then you will have to create the ArrayList like bellow:

```
ArrayList<MyRow> myRows = new ArrayList<MyRow>();
```

In general, when you want to store more than one property in a variable you need to create a class/object representing your model.

Answer (score 0):

Considering your row is mapped to a class, it seem you want to do something like the following:

```
public class YourClass{
  // private type propertyName;
  // getters/setters
 }
```

Where you need the list, create an ArrayList of type YourClass as

```
 YourClass obj = new YourClass(); // hopefully with values populated either using constructor or via setters
 List<YourClass> list =  new ArrayList<>();
 list.add(obj)  // add you objects.
```